# I want to process bulk of wav files at a time and convert them all into text like hindi english tamil etc by using python programming

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import os 
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence


r = sr.Recognizer()


def get_large_audio_transcription(path,):
    
    """
    Splitting the large audio file into chunks
    and apply speech recognition on each of these chunks
    """
    
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(path)  
    chunks = split_on_silence(sound,
        min_silence_len = 500,
        silence_thresh = sound.dBFS-16,
        
        keep_silence=500,
    )
    folder_name = "audio-chunks"
    
    if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
    whole_text = ""
    for i, audio_chunk in enumerate(chunks, start=1):
        
        chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
        audio_chunk.export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
        with sr.AudioFile(chunk_filename) as source:
            audio_listened = r.record(source)
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio_listened,language="hi-IN")
            except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
                print("Error:", str(e))
            else:
                text = f"{text.capitalize()}. "
                print(chunk_filename, ":", text)
                whole_text += text
    return whole_text


path = "G:\ezimex\audiowav\wav1.wav"
print("\nFull text:",get_large_audio_transcription(path))
```

Using this code I pass one audio at a time but it takes to much time to process all audio one by one into text.

I want to process all wav files process at once and covert all into text. please help me to solve it using python. the all audio files stores in a folder `audiowav`.

How to process these bulked files at once using python and convert into text?

Comment: Which part of your transcription takes too long time?

Comment: means if i process one audio at a time then it took long time to process all audios. Actually, i want to process all audio at a time and convert them to text at once not one by one.In the code there is one audio is processed.but now i want to process bulk of audio at once and convert them into text.for this process i didn't know how to process all

Comment: Are you sure that processing all the audio at a time would be faster?

Comment: This looks impossible unless you can get timestamps for each word (or sentence) in the speech-to-text output. Figure out if it's possble with the API.

Comment: You can test out whether it'll actually be faster do to it in parallel by running the x copies of your script at the same time (using different source files); make sure that you'll actually get a speedup before doing the work. I'm guessing your processing speed will be limited by the number of cores available to your program, The `Pool` abstraction in multiprocessing could be a quick fix to get multi-core performance: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html